# Error Updating a Chromebook's Organizational Unit with Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-admin-sdk, chromebook

I have been experiencing an issue recently with a Google Script code I wrote to update a few Chromebooks' organization units.

Here is a portion of the code that I am running:

```
let admin = AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.get("my_customer", active_deviceid[serial_index])
admin.annotatedAssetId = device_ID.toString()
admin.annotatedLocation = name
admin.orgUnitPath = _location_(device_ID).toString().toUpperCase()

AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.update(admin, 'my_customer', active_deviceid[serial_index])
```

Once the script executes I get the following error:

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to directory.chromeosdevices.update failed with error: Invalid Input: Inconsistent Orgunit id and path in request - 11006550017573025, /1 SCHOOLS/COVID LOANERS
```

What is strange is that if I comment or remove "**admin.orgUnitPath = *location*(device_ID).toString().toUpperCase()**" the script will run fine. It seems the orgUnitPath is causing this error.

I tried the following:

1. Removing the first slash "/"
2. Do only 1 Chromebook
3. Remove and reapply the AdminDirectory
4. Run previous scripts that were used to change the OrgUnitPath
5. Added quotes on the beginning and end of the OrgUnitPath
6. Converted the path to String with toString()
7. used Stript() function to eliminate any empty spaces

All the above attempts failed to fix this issue. I will also include an image of an error I am getting from a previous script I made that used to work about a year ago that also changes the OrgUnitPath.
[image: Google Script same error message from old script that used to work]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked whether `_location_(device_ID).toString().toUpperCase()` is returning your desired orgUnitPath? Also, does this happen with any org unit, or just this one? Can you test this with simpler paths, not including multiple levels, white spaces and so on?

Comment: Hi @iamblichus yes I used Logger.log to see the desired path for multiple OrgUnitPath and it was correct but all the paths still provide the same error. I have not tried a simpler path, I will test it and leave another comment.

Comment: Hello again, I tried a shorter path  "/5 TECH DEPT" and still it fail with the same error message. 

Out of curiosity, I changed a user's OU with Google Script instead and it did work, however, changing an OU for a Chromebook is still not working.

Comment: If you try a simpler OU path, not containing any white spaces, do you get the same behavior?

Comment: Have you try to get the object details, then move it from the GUI to the desired OU and get the object details again to compare vs before? Looking at the reference https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/orgunits/update I am a bit confused about the `customerID` because the number in the error is the user `ID` and the `customerID` is unique for the tenant, so every useraccount has the same `customerID` but unique `id`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason there has been a change that now requires the orgUnitId *in addition* to the orgUnitPath.

So before you run AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.update you need to obtain the orgUnitId  and update that property

```
var orgUnitPathStr = "/Tech Dept/Storage"
admin.orgUnitId = AdminDirectory.Orgunits.get("my_customer",orgUnitPathStr.substring(1)).orgUnitId;
//substring(1) above removes the first slash in the orgUnitPath, which is required for this method
```

Credit for hints:
https://github.com/taers232c/GAMADV-XTD3/issues/225